# Hashicorp Consul Watches & Snapshot problem (with Docker container)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I'm trying to do some disaster prevention job. The backup flow is shown:

Watches handler: "K/V changes detected" => evoke shell "do snapshot save"

watch config:

```
{
  "watches": [
    {
        "type": "keyprefix",
        "prefix": "www/",
        "args": ["/consul/run.sh"]
    }
  ]
}
```

shell (/consul/run.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "start backup snapshot" >> /consul/trigger.log
consul snapshot save /consul/keyvalue.bak
echo "end backup snapshot" >> /consul/trigger.log
```

When K/V has changing that invoke shell indeed without any error log (even echo messages has stored in the /consul/trigger.log ), but I can't find my backup file in any directory.

Can somebody explain to me why backup file is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work under Docker Compose by performing the following steps. Perhaps you'll see a successful snapshot after following these instructions.

1. Create a `docker-compose.yaml` file.

   ```yaml
     ---
   version: "3.8"
   services:
     consul:
       image: consul:1.10.2
       ports:
         - 8500:8500
       environment:
         CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: |
           {
             "watches": [
               {
                   "type": "keyprefix",
                   "prefix": "www/",
                   "args": ["/consul/run.sh"]
               }
             ]
           }
       volumes:
         - ./consul_data/:/consul/
   ```
2. Create the `consul_data` with a few sub-directories which are required by Consul.

   ```
   $ mkdir -p consul_data/{config,data}
   ```
3. Create `run.sh` within the `consul_data/` directory.

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh

   echo "start backup snapshot" >> /consul/trigger.log
   consul snapshot save /consul/keyvalue.bak
   echo "end backup snapshot" >> /consul/trigger.log
   ```
4. Ensure that `run.sh` is executable.

   ```
   chmod +x consul_data/run.sh
   ```
5. Start Consul.

   ```
   $ docker-compose up
   ```
6. In another terminal, use `consul kv put` to create a key under the `www/` prefix.

   ```
   $ consul kv put www/test
   Success! Data written to: www/test
   ```
7. In the previous terminal, I can then see the configured watch firing, and the snapshot being saved.

   ```
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:11.741Z [DEBUG] agent.http: Request finished: method=PUT url=/v1/kv/www/test from=192.168.32.1:65036 latency=657.891µs
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:11.741Z [DEBUG] agent.http: Request finished: method=GET url=/v1/kv/www/?index=21&recurse= from=127.0.0.1:44946 latency=24.915165128s
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:11.927Z [INFO]  agent.fsm: snapshot created: duration=261.695µs
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:11.927Z [INFO]  agent.server.raft: starting snapshot up to: index=26
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:11.928Z [INFO]  agent.server.raft: snapshot complete up to: index=26
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:11.979Z [DEBUG] agent.http: Request finished: method=GET url=/v1/snapshot from=127.0.0.1:44974 latency=52.717138ms
   consul_1  | 2021-09-07T05:48:12.023Z [DEBUG] agent: watch handler output: watch_handler=[/consul/run.sh] output="Saved and verified snapshot to index 26
   consul_1  | "
   ```
8. Lastly, confirm the snapshot is present.

   ```
   $ file consul_data/keyvalue.bak
   consul_data/keyvalue.bak: gzip compressed data, original size modulo 2^32 9728
   ```